# Create .Net Core 3.1 console app to Debian 9, should it just work?

Tags: c#, debian

If I create a simple .Net Core 3.1 console app on my Windows machine, should I be able to copy the output folder over to Debian 9 machine and the console program just work?

Because it's not.

./ConsoleApp1.exe - does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you'll also find a 'ConsoleApp1.dll' file in your output folder, which is your actual application (the .exe is only a wrapper for Windows).

You should be able to run your application on any platform with the .NET Core runtime installed like this:

```
dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll
```

Comment: What’s the difference between using ./ConsoleApp1.dll and dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll.

Comment: ConsoleApp1.dll is not an executable from an OS perspective, so you can't run it like './ConsoleApp1.dll'. In the other case (dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll), dotnet is the platform specific executable provided by the runtime, and you provide your platform independent dll as an argument.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that there are other options for building your app, see documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/